# SharePoint plugin development automatization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, visual-studio, deployment

I use Visual Studio 2017 to build and deploy SharePoint-hosted plugin to dev sharepoint environment. 
Can I authomatize this process? I want SharePoint plugin to be automatically deployed to dev server on commit to master branch.

I can't find any CLI tools for building or deploying SharePoint plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not expert but maybe these points help. If you are using TFS

- Configure build server to build SharePoint full trust (WSP) solutions: https://matthiasbaumann.me/2013/03/10/setting-up-tfs-build-server-for-sharepoint-2013/ and there's also an archived CodePlex project: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=officesharepointci
- Use PowerShell to deploy your soltion to a SharePoint farm, using commands like: [Install-SPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) an [Add-SPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps)

Edit: I see you are using SharePoint Online. Maybe this post helps: https://writeabout.net/2016/03/23/how-to-deploy-sharepoint-apps-with-vsts-release-management/

Comment: I cant find how to use these commands Install-SPSolution an Add-SPSolution. I see they are part of sharepoint-server module but there are no installation instruction for this module. Unfortunately, sharepoint-pnp module works for me but doesn't provide commands I need. (I need to deploy .app|.wsp file to sharepoint site)

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online or Onpremises? These commands only work for onpremises

Comment: With Add-SPSolution, there's a sample on the page. Just point to the WSP and add it to SharePoint. After you've added it, you can run Install-SPSolution and provide the filename to instal it. This post is more step-by-step: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/add-and-deploy-solution-in-sharepoint-central-administration/

Comment: I use SharePoint Online. Also I found [Install-PnPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/install-pnpsolution?view=sharepoint-ps), will it work for Sharepoint Online? I tried to use that command, it fell with error "File not found exception" but file path was correct. I guess problem is in PackageId, where can I find it? I tried to use all ids from AppManifest and .csproj file. They didn't work.

Comment: These commands are targeted at SharePoint onpremises. Deploying WSP's is not supported on SharePoint online, except for some declarative sandbox solutions.